# Implementing Rest API into rails. Where to put the code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest

I'm trying to implement zoom.us Rest API into my rails app (example: https://github.com/mllocs/zoomus and https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/sections/200305463-API ), but i have no idea where to put this part of the code. Or how to call it. (i know that i'm suppose to change the xxx to my credentials at least.) Is there a specific ruby gem that I should be installing first prior to working with a Rest API?

```
 require 'zoomus'

Zoomus.configure do |c|
  c.api_key = 'xxx'
  c.api_secret = 'xxx'
end

zoomus_client = Zoomus.new

user_list = zoomus_client.user_list
user_list['users'].each do |user|
  user_id = user['id']
  puts zoomus_client.meeting_list(:host_id => user_id)
end

begin
  user_list = zoomus_client.user_list!
rescue Zoomus::Error => exception
  puts 'Something went wrong'
end
```

Comment: Then the question comes why do you even want to use rails, why not Sinatra if your goal is just to use this API. If not please go through the basics of rails first then come back and you should be able to identify places.

Comment: First time hearing about Sinatra (i'm very new to rails still). I'll research it!

Comment: EDIT: I'm not using ONLY this api. i'm implementing this api into my existing rails project.

Comment: Then you should look into the basics first like how files are arranged, where to places files related to model, same goes for config and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you that all configuration of zoom put into your config->environments->development.rb or productin.rb files like:

```
Zoomus.configure do |c|
  c.api_key = 'xxx'
  c.api_secret = 'xxx'
end
```

and put your other code into files where you want to access or use (api, controller,method,class)

```
zoomus_client = Zoomus.new

user_list = zoomus_client.user_list
user_list['users'].each do |user|
  user_id = user['id']
  puts zoomus_client.meeting_list(:host_id => user_id)
end

begin
  user_list = zoomus_client.user_list!
rescue Zoomus::Error => exception
  puts 'Something went wrong'
end
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bundler, you don't need to first line. When you add `gem 'zoomus'` to your Gemfile, bundle, then run Rails, those gems will be required automatically unless explicitly told otherwise (using `require: false` option)

Normally the `configure` block goes into config/initializers/zoomus.rb. Any file inside of config/initializers/ will be loaded during the boot process.

The rest of the code really depends on when and where you use this service. My recommendation would be to wrap these calls into plain objects that sit in app/services. Call out to those classes wherever you need to, whether it's an ActiveJob worker, controller, or model.

Really it's impossible to answer your question without context, and even with context you will get different answers from different people. Where to place code has been a hot topic of debate in Rails for many years.

Comment: I basically want to create a meeting by pressing a button. https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201363053-REST-Meeting-API#collapseCreateAMeeting

According to that document, it says "Create a meeting on Zoom, return the created meeting URL." 

This is my first time working with API's, and I'm very lost.

Answer (score 0):

This stuff:

```
Zoomus.configure do |c|
  c.api_key = 'xxx'
  c.api_secret = 'xxx'
end
ZoomusClient = Zoomus.new
```

should be in a file `config/initializers/zoomus.rb`.

Note that I changed `zoomus_client` to `ZoomusClient` so that it is a constant. This is so it will be available in the other files.

Make sure you're not checking in the api credentials into source control, or they might get published to Github. Use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) or something for this.

The rest of the code can be called by any method in your rails app.

```
  puts ZoomusClient.meeting_list(
    host_id: ZoomusClient.user_list['users'][0].id
  )
```